# z-scoring or normalization in LIBSVM

Tags: normalization, svm, matlab, libsvm

I'm using LIBSVM in MATLAB.
It seems svmtrain.c doesn't have data normalization function.
I wonder if there is any normalizing or z-scoring function in LIBSVM package itself?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What version of MATLAB & libraries?

Comment: MATLAB R2014a and LIBSVM 3.18. I saw svm-scale.c code but it doesn't seem that this code is used in svmtrain or svmpredict functions.

Comment: The MATLAB [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) has such functions.

Comment: That means LIBSVM itself doesn't provide that function? I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MATLAB [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) has these. It seems unlikely LIBSVM would duplicate them, but looking quickly I haven't been able confirm either way. If you don't have access you should be able to get definitions eg via [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11027457/3404097).